# SOAP request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I was trying to send a SOAP request whereas my request header and requestbody are in XML format. I tried using node module 'request' but its not working. I am clueless here. My service action also included in the header.

```js
//request body
var requestBody = '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> '+
                    '<sample>'+
                        '<sampleData>'+
                            '<r1>'+
                                '<type>'+ 2 +'</type>'+
                            '</r1>'+
                            '<r2>'+
                                '<r3>'+
                                    '<test>'+ "1234" +'</test>'+
                                '</r3>'+
                            '</r2>'+
                        '</sampleDate>'+
                    '</sample>'+
                    '</s:Body>' ;



//soap header
var requestHeaders = ' <soapenv:Header>' + 
    '<add:MessageID xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">' + getMessageID() + '</add:MessageID>' +
    '<add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">'+ getAction() +'</add:Action>'+
    '<add:To xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">' + getDestinationEndPoint() +'</add:To>' +
    '<link:TransactionFlowLink xmlns:link="blahbalhbal"/>' +
    '<oas:Security xmlns:oas="">'+
        '<oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">'+
            '<oas:Username>'+ getUserName() + '</oas:Username>'+
             '<oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'+ getPasswordDigest() +'</oas:Password>'+
            '<oas1:Created>'+ getTimestamp() + '</oas1:Created>'+
        '</oas:UsernameToken>'+
    '</oas:Security>'+
    
'</soapenv:Header>';


var requestOptions = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': url,
  'qs': { 'wsdl': ''},
  'headers': requestHeaders,
  'body': requestBody,
  'timeout': 5000
};
//console.log(requestHeaders);
//call to WS

 request(requestOptions, function (error, response) {

console.log(resonse);//confused here what else need to do for getting response

});
```

Or do we need to use any other node module for this?

Comment: You confuse the soap header with the http headers in the http request. Both the soap header and body need to go into the (http) request body. For the http header you probably want to set someting like `Content-type: txt/xml` also.

Comment: @Erik: Thanks.Tried that also but no luck.Which node module can be used to call this soap service?